# transferring data from different clock domains using dual port ram(FPGA)

Tags: vhdl, fpga, intel-fpga

I want to transfer a frame from 143 Mhz clock domain to 49 Mhz clock domain to view the frames through VGA. For a test I tried to transfer a vertical and horizontal white lines to view through the VGA port. But I'm not getting it right.

What I expect is:
[image]
(click to enlarge)

But what I'm getting is:
[image]
(click to enlarge)

I don't know what I have done wrong. I am stuck here. If someone could help me, it would be great.

(All the VHD files are uploaded and the top level is "fifo.vhd". The board I'm using is DE1-SoC)

fifo:

```
**library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;


entity fifo is
port(
clk : in std_logic;
HS,VS,VGACLK : out std_logic;
R,G,B : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
end fifo;

architecture main of fifo is 
-----------signals----------------------
signal clk_49,clk_143 : std_logic;
signal datain, dataout : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal addr2,addr1 : integer range 0 to 2047 := 0;
signal hpos,vpos : integer range 0 to 2047 := 0;
---------------------------------------------------
component pll is
        port (
            clk_clk       : in  std_logic := 'X'; -- clk
            reset_reset_n : in  std_logic := 'X'; -- reset_n
            clk_49_clk    : out std_logic;        -- clk
            clk_143_clk   : out std_logic         -- clk
        );
end component pll;

component simple_dual_port_ram_dual_clock is
    port 
    (
        rclk    : in std_logic;
        wclk    : in std_logic;
        raddr   : in natural range 0 to 2047;
        waddr   : in natural range 0 to 2047;
        data    : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        we      : in std_logic := '1';
        q       : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end component simple_dual_port_ram_dual_clock;

component sync is
    port(
        clk : in std_logic;
        data : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        hsync, vsync: out std_logic;
        R,G,B : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end component sync;

begin
VGACLK <= clk_49;

u2 : component sync
          port map (clk_49,dataout,HS,VS,R,G,B);

u0 : component pll
        port map (
            clk_clk       => clk,         --     clk.clk
            reset_reset_n => '1',         --   reset.reset_n
            clk_49_clk    => clk_49,      --  clk_49.clk
            clk_143_clk   => clk_143       -- clk_143.clk
        ); 
u1 : component simple_dual_port_ram_dual_clock
        port map (clk_143,clk_49,addr2,addr1,datain,'1',dataout);  


process(clk_143)
begin
if(clk'event and clk='1') then
-------loop-----------------
    if(hpos<1055)then 
    hpos<=hpos+1;
    else
    hpos<=0;
        if(vpos<625)then
            vpos<=vpos+1;
            else
            vpos<=0;
        end if;
    end if;
------------------------------
    if (addr1 = addr2) then
    ------do nothing-------------
    else
        if(hpos = 600 or vpos = 300) then
            datain<= (others=> '1');
        else
            datain<= (others=> '0');
        end if;
        addr1 <= addr1 + 1;
        if(addr1 = 1055)then
            addr1<=0;
        end if;
    end if; 
end if;
end process;

process(clk_49)
begin
if(clk'event and clk='1') then
    addr2 <= addr2 + 1;
    if(addr2 = 1055)then
        addr2<=0;
    end if; 
end if;
end process;

end main;**
```

Ram:

```
-- Quartus Prime VHDL Template
-- Simple Dual-Port RAM with different read/write addresses and
-- different read/write clock

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity simple_dual_port_ram_dual_clock is

    generic 
    (
        DATA_WIDTH : natural := 8;
        ADDR_WIDTH : natural := 11
    );

    port 
    (
        rclk    : in std_logic;
        wclk    : in std_logic;
        raddr   : in natural range 0 to 2**ADDR_WIDTH - 1;
        waddr   : in natural range 0 to 2**ADDR_WIDTH - 1;
        data    : in std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
        we      : in std_logic := '1';
        q       : out std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH -1) downto 0)
    );

end simple_dual_port_ram_dual_clock;

architecture rtl of simple_dual_port_ram_dual_clock is

    -- Build a 2-D array type for the RAM
    subtype word_t is std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
    type memory_t is array(2**ADDR_WIDTH-1 downto 0) of word_t;

    -- Declare the RAM signal.  
    signal ram : memory_t;

begin

    process(wclk)
    begin
    if(rising_edge(wclk)) then 
        if(we = '1') then
            ram(waddr) <= data;
        end if;
    end if;
    end process;

    process(rclk)
    begin
    if(rising_edge(rclk)) then 
        q <= ram(raddr);
    end if;
    end process;

end rtl;
```

Sync :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity sync is
port(
clk : in std_logic;
data : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
hsync, vsync: out std_logic;
R,G,B : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
end sync;

architecture main of sync is
signal hpos : integer range 0 to 1055:=0;
signal vpos : integer range 0 to 625:=0;
begin
process(clk)
begin
if(clk'event and clk='1')then
-----------------------------------
--loop-----------------------------
    if(hpos<1055)then 
    hpos<=hpos+1;
    else
    hpos<=0;
        if(vpos<625)then
            vpos<=vpos+1;
            else
            vpos<=0;
        end if;
    end if;
--------------------------------------
--SYNC-----------------------------------
   if(hpos<80)then
        hsync<='0';
        else
        hsync<='1';
    end if;
   if(vpos<3)then
        vsync<='0';
        else
        vsync<='1';
    end if;
--------------------------------------  
   if((hpos<240)or(hpos>1040)or(vpos<24)or(vpos>623))then
    R<=(OTHERS=>'0');
    G<=(OTHERS=>'0');
    B<=(OTHERS=>'0');
    else
    R<=data;
    G<=data;
    B<=data;
    end if;
----------------------------
end if;
end process;
end main;
```

Comment: Have you tried to test if you have your video timings right? Afaik [800x600@60Hz has 1056x628 pixels at 40 MHz](http://tinyvga.com/vga-timing/800x600@60Hz). Not 1056x626@49MHz.

Comment: @JHBonarius I tried the frames without cross clock domains, it worked perfectly. DE1 usermanual says it as 1055x625. My main goal is to change the clock domains.

Comment: In architecture main of fifo you have two processes sensitive to clk_143 and clk_49 respectively. However both infer sequential logic on the rising edge of clk (`if(clk'event and clk = '1') then`). Your dual port ram is 2 ** 11  (2048) deep while your frame interval is 1056 x 626 (661056) pixel times. Your ram can't be used as a frame buffer (It's not exactly a frame interval  of pixels (`we => '1'`) nor 800 x 600 (480000), the visible portion of the frame). "If someone could help me, it would be great." isn't [a specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).